# Return a function from a nested function javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to return an outer function from a nested  one in javascript?
I have something like this:

```
function outer(){

    $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){

    })


    $(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function(event){

    // i want to exit from here when this event fires

    })

}
```

Comment: The outer function returns immediately.

Comment: Adding event handlers doesn't wait for the events to occur. They're asynchronous. So your question doesn't really make sense, since there's nothing to return from `outer()`.

Comment: Ok yes, what i want actually is to exit from those event listeners after the second event fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others already said, you can't return from something that might or might not happen in the future. If the intent is to return some value from the event handler you could use a promise.

Keep in mind that a promise can only be resolved once. Pressing the button multiple times wont fire the promise handlers again.

```js
function outer() {
  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    // ...
  });

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    $(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function (event) {
      resolve("Hello World!");
    });
  });
}

outer().then(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" />
```

If you want something that can fire multiple times, accept an callback function and call that instead.

```js
function outer(callback) {
  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    // ...
  });

  $(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function (event) {
    callback("Hello World!");
  });
}

outer(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" />
```

---

Based on your comment you aren't looking for a return value at all, but rather something like this:

```js
function outer() {
  function handleCheckboxChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
  }

  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", handleCheckboxChange);

  $(document).one("click", "input[type='submit']", function (event) {
    $(document).off("change", "input[type='checkbox']", handleCheckboxChange);
    console.log("Hello World!");
  });
}

outer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="submit" />
```

The jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) says:

> To remove events bound with `.on()`, see [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Thank this is really helpful. What i would like is to handle many times the first event and after the second fires to stop not only the second event but also the first one, is this possibile?

Comment: I need the first event handler (input[type='checkbox']) to handle events until the second event handler (input[type='submit']) fires, and after that i need to stop both event listeners

Comment: @user21 Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those are event listeners. They fire when the event is triggered, not when a function is called. If you want you can put a function *in* an event listener, and call it outside of the listener as well, like this:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
    console.log("logging function")
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => doSomething()

doSomething()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in my code i need to activate those events listener after the i run the function outer. And basically i need to stop those event listeners after the second event fires the first time

Comment: @user21 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: This is for js events not jquery i think

Comment: @user21 Correct. I'm not sure what the equivalent is for jQuery, but jQuery is a subset of Javascript, so any Javascript code will work in your jQuery. Google "jQuery remove event listener" and you should find something useful.